# React Router 6.2.2. issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I got a new laptop and just installed Node. React, etc to build a new app. I created my app and it's using react-router-dom 6.2.2 and it's giving me errors such as:
[ uncaught error: Invalid hook call, Hooks can... ]

I only have the folder structure setup and this on my index.js and app.js files

[app.js]

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

React.DOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={ <App /> } />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementID('root')
 );
```

and my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
{ 
   <div className="header>
      Title
   </div>
   <Routes>
     <Route path={'/'} />
     <Route path={ './templates/temples' } element={<Template/>} />
  </Routes> 
}
```

what am I missing? What would give me that hook error? If I take the  code out of the app.js file the app runs, however, I need the navigation

Comment: where are you importing 'Routes' component in the index.js file? It does not look like you're returning valid JSX in the App component.

Comment: This is a typo: import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
, it's import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; I typed it wrong since it's on another laptop

Comment: This has been resolved. I blew away the project, recreated it and no issues, Not sure what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

please import  from 'react-router-dom' first, then try again.

```
 import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```